# Apache Apisix state serialization

Tags: api, configuration, state, api-gateway, apache-apisix

I want to know if APISIX can load routes/upstreams/consumers basically any ressource
within the startup process by using something like a config file?

At the moment I only see the option to start APISIX and then call the API
to construct the ressources, but I do not want to have to create all ressources
again and again when redeployed this way.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When deploying new APISIX instances:
   1.1 If they use the same configuration, you can connect to the same etcd.
   1.2 If they're in a different environment, for example, Dev, UAT, and Production. You can do `etcdcli snapshot xxx` to export the configurations.
2. Yes, APISIX supports `YAML` configurations, which means you can setup all resources in the `standalone` mode instead of using `Admin API` each time.